# Background image not covering the whole space

Tags: css, parallax

I am sure I am missing something simple, but I can't seem to find it.

On [michelleforboe.com](http://michelleforboe.com), I am trying to get the background image to cover the whole space of a div.  I am using calc to set the height of the div, but the div is resolving slightly higher that what it should be.  Also, if you scroll down & back up, the black bar at the bottom of the image is even larger.  There is a another div sitting on top of the image; I had thought maybe that was causing the extra space, but I don't think it is.  Anyone see what I am missing?

```
.home-section-1 .wrap {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.home .site-inner {
    margin-top: 140px; 
} 
.home-section-1.widget-area {
    background-size: 100% calc(100vw/2.9);
    background-position: 50% 50%; 
    height: calc(100vw/2.9);
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
} 
#text-7 {
  height: calc(100vw/2.9);
}
#text-7 .widget-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; 
}
#text-7 .widget-wrap .textwidget {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#text-7 a.button {
    font-size: 2vw;
    padding: 1vw;
}   
.home-section-1 .widget-wrap {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
.home-section-1.widget-area {
background-size: cover !important;
background-position: 50% 50%; 
height: auto;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

If u wanna full screen of image then remove height from css

```
.home-section-1.widget-area {
background-size: cover !important;
background-position: 50% 50%;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried using cover on the background-size, but it makes the image larger.  I was trying to set the div to the size of the image aspect ratio (using calc) so that the image would fit & scale well.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Oops, hit enter - so the image on my browser is 1583.  Divide that by 2.9 & the height should be 546.  But, the height on my browser is 552.  Seems that something (maybe .textwidget?) is pushing the home-section-1 to be taller.  And, when I scroll down and then back up, the black bar is larger than when I first go to that page.